# CDF constant on an interval that has a smooth PDF

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis

I am looking for examples of Cumulative Distribution Functions $F$ which are constant on an interval but do have a density $f \in C^1$. Any reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: isn't f, by definition, the derivative, and hence, 0 identically for constant F?

Comment: Yes, but I mean that $F$ is constant on an interval but not on the whole support of $F$, so indeed $f$ must be $0$ on such interval but outside not.

Comment: Take any smooth nonnegative compactly supported function $g$ which vanishes outside $(0,1)$ and have integral $\frac{1}{2}$ (we can always rescale any bump function). Define density $g(x) = f(x) + f(x-2)$. Then, it's $C^1$ (in fact can be made $C^\infty$), have integral $1$ and is non-negative (hence a probability distribution), and yet the CDF of such distribution is constant on $(1,2)$.

Comment: The CDF of $F(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$, $F(x)=2x^2$ for $0 \le x \le \frac12$, $F(x)=1-2(1-x)^2$ for $\frac12 \le x \le 1$ and $F(x)=1$ for $x \ge 1$  is constant on the interval $[2,3]$ with a density of $0$ there.  Its density is $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$, $f(x)=4x$ for $0 \le x \le \frac12$, $f(x)=4(1-x)$ for $\frac12 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \ge 1$